# compare Long value in java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Integer == int allowed in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672317/integer-int-allowed-in-java)

What is the difference between the following two statements

```
Long l1 = 2L;
if(l1 == 2)
    System.out.println("EQUAL");                         
if(l1.longValue() == 2)
    System.out.println("EQUAL");
```

They both are giving same result "EQUAL".But my doubt is Long is object. How is it equal?

Comment: This is due to [auto-unboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

Comment: It's because of auto boxing and unboxing feature of Java

Comment: or is there any useful link

Comment: l1.longValue() will return the same value as what has l1?.I am confusing with this

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As already pointed out in the comments, when doing

```
if(l1 == 2)
```

`Long` `l1` gets automatically unboxed to its primitive type, `long`. So the comparison is between `long` and `int`.

In the second case, [`l1.longValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#longValue()) will return the `long` value, as a primitive, of the `Long` represented by the `Long` object, so the comparison will be again between `long` and `int`. Answering [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14642432/compare-long-value-in-java/14642560#comment20457049_14642432), take a look at [What is the main difference between primitive type and wrapper class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13339918/851811)

The link given in the comments about [autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) covers this subject quite well.

Answer (score -1):

This behaviour is explained by widening and boxing.

In the first example,

```
if(l1 == 2)
```

what happens is as follows:

1: The compiler notices that you are comparing a wrapper (Long) with a primitive value (int), so it boxes the primitive, resulting in:

`if (l1 == new Integer(2))`

since 2 is an int (it lacks the 'L' at the end).

2: The compiler now notices that we are comparing a Long with an Integer, so it widens the Integer to a Long, resulting in:

`if (l1 == new Long(new Integer(2))`

3: Now we are comparing two Longs.

The other case is simpler, here the result is simply:

> if (2L == 2)

comparing the primitive values, which is allowed even though they are different types.

Comment: Not sure about your explanation about the first example. I think it's _unboxing_ of `l1` that's happening here, not _boxing_ of `2` into `Integer`. If it was that way, the only thing that could explain the `==` operator returning `true` would be caching, which wouldn't be a valid explanation if it was doing `new Integer(2)` anyway. Also, doing `new Long(123456) == 123456` returns `true`, and it seems to be a value out of the caching range.