# Difference between Primitive and non-primitive datatypes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop, types, abstract-data-type

I am not able to understand exactly what is difference between primitive  and non primitive data types in JavaScript even it is declared using same name i.e var.

Comment: Primitive have value, non-primitives have reference, this is the main difference

Comment: Also, primitives are not initially instantiated as objects, whereas non-primitives are (I think this is the reason for value vs. reference as mentioned above).

Comment: Types don't have anything to do with variables in JS, they are not "declared". They only belong to the values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the main difference between primitive type and wrapper class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339918/what-is-the-main-difference-between-primitive-type-and-wrapper-class)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Data Types (JavaScript):

Primary Data Types
The primary (primitive) data types are:
String, Number, Boolean

Composite Data Types
The composite (reference) data types are:
Object, Array

Special Data Types
The special data types are:
Null, Undefined
```

Click [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/7wkd9z69(v=vs.94).aspx) for details:

```
  var test1 = 1;
  var test2 = "Something";
  var test3 = true;
  var test4 = {};
  var test5 = new Array();
  var test6 = new Date();
  var test7;
  var test8 = null;

  alert(typeof (test1)); //number
  alert(typeof (test2)); //string
  alert(typeof (test3)); //boolean
  alert(typeof (test4)); //object
  alert(typeof (test5)); //object
  alert(typeof (test6)); //object
  alert(typeof (test7)); //undefined
  alert(typeof (test8)); //object
```

Answer (score 4):

Javascript has five primitive data types:
1. number
2. string
3. boolean
4. undefined
5. null

Anything that doesn’t belong to any of these five primitive types is considered an object.

First 3  data types has a corresponding object constructor. For example

```
var word = "something";
```

And then as an object:

```
 var word = new String("something");
```

For object constructor notice the `new` keyword. It creates object  reference.

Another thing to notice that

```
var greeting = "something";
var word = new String("something");
greeting == word ----> True as their value is same
greeting === word -----> False because there value same but type is different .
```

As for var keyword being same  for all the cases,remember that Javascript is dynamically typed language. That means it resolves data type checking during runtime rather than compile time(like Java, C++ ).

This makes javascript extremely powerful. Though this unique feature has drawback too. Please co through this wikipedia for details:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Static_and_dynamic_type_checking_in_practice

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures

Primitive Data types in ES6 are:
Boolean
Null
Undefined
Number
String
Symbol

The other data type which is not a primitive one is
Object

Primitive data types are immutable values.

Answer (score 1):

Primitive Datatypes are 
1. Number
2. String
3. Boolean
4. Undefined
5. Null

Non-Primitive Datatypes are 
1.Object
2.Array
3.RegExp

Answer (score 1):

**Primitive datatype** are type provided by the programming language as the basic building block. like: number,string,null,undefined,Boolean.  
Primitive datatype get the memory allocation at compile time.

**Derived datatype** are type which are derived from the existing primitive datatype bundled together like: array,object etc.
Derived datatype just get the reference to that memory allocation where value are saved.

Answer (score 0):

**The latest ECMAScript standard defines eight data types:**

1. String
2. Boolean
3. Number
4. BigInt
5. Null
6. Undefined
7. Symbol
8. Object

**Note :- Arrays do not belong to this list because they are objects as well. This is a common confusion among developers who assume that arrays are a special data type in Javascript.**

> **Now bifurcate the data type**

There are two types of data types in JavaScript:

1. Primitive values (String, Boolean, Number, BigInt, Null, Undefined, Symbol )
2. Non-primitive values is also called **object references** (Object,Array)

Answer (score -1):

It's simple, just remember primitive data types means the data type which contain a single value, like 1, 'test', true,

Non-primitive data-types means the data type which contain multiple values or complex data called non-primitive like an object etc.