# AopInvocationException: in @Autowieired in JUnit

Tags: java, spring, junit

In my java spring mvc application, i am using the below code:

The repository:

```
@Repository
public interface TransactionRepository  extends JpaRepository<Transactions ,Long >{

    @Query(value = "SELECT sum( value)  FROM Transactions  inner  join Customer on  Transactions.customer_id=Customer.id   where merchant_id= ?1 and age_class= ?2 ", nativeQuery=true)
    public double getOverAllValue(String merchantID,String ageGroup);


}
```

and then i made a serivce which works based on this `@Repository`:

```
@Service
public class IncomeDataService {

    @Autowired
    TransactionRepository transactionRepo;

    public ArrayList<Double> dataCollector(int merchantID){
        ArrayList<Double> data= new ArrayList<Double>(); 
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
            data.add( transactionRepo.getOverAllValue(Integer.toString(merchantID),Integer.toString(i)));

        return data;
    }
```

and then i am trying to test the written service using the `junit`:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = SEBApplication.class)
public class IncomeDataServiceTest {

    @Autowired 
    IncomeDataService incomeDataService;

    @Test
    public void testDataCollector() {
        System.out.println(incomeDataService.dataCollector(1));
    }

}
```

But, when i run my test it complains with:

```
org.springframework.aop.AopInvocationException: Null return value from advice does not match primitive return type for: public abstract double ee.seb.domain.repository.TransactionRepository.getOverAllValue(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
```

Comment: Change return type of your query to wrapper class:Double

Comment: oh man, thx. so what is the difference between `double`, and `Double`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339918/what-is-the-main-difference-between-primitive-type-and-wrapper-class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your Query's return type from primitive data type `double` to `Double` Because your query can return `null` value which will be accepted by wrapper class and not by primitive, so your final Query will be like this:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT sum( value)  FROM Transactions  inner  join Customer on  Transactions.customer_id=Customer.id   where merchant_id= ?1 and age_class= ?2 ", nativeQuery=true)
    public Double getOverAllValue(String merchantID,String ageGroup);
```